# Loading a torchscript model in C++: Cannot initialize CUDA without ATen_cuda library

Tags: c++, windows, pytorch

I have built a CNN with Pytorch with GPU support. It works fine in python and I would like to import it in my C++ application using VS2017. I am following these instructions [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html) and [here](https://medium.com/@boonboontongbuasirilai/building-pytorch-c-integration-libtorch-with-ms-visual-studio-2017-44281f9921ea).
I can build and run the application, but I get this error when loading the model:

```
error loading the model
Cannot initialize CUDA without ATen_cuda library. PyTorch splits its backend into two shared 
libraries: a CPU library and a CUDA library; this error has occurred because you are trying to use 
some CUDA functionality, but the CUDA library has not been loaded by the dynamic linker for some 
reason.  The CUDA library MUST be loaded, EVEN IF you don't directly use any symbols from the CUDA 
library! One common culprit is a lack of -Wl,--no-as-needed in your link arguments; many dynamic 
linkers will delete dynamic library dependencies if you don't depend on any of their symbols.  You 
can check if this has occurred by using ldd on your binary to see if there is a dependency on 
*_cuda.so library. (initCUDA at 
C:\w\1\s\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen/detail/CUDAHooksInterface.h:63)
(no backtrace available)
```

I cannot find any `ATen_cuda file` in the `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1`.
Has anyone a Windows C++ VS2017 Pytorch with GPU working sample?

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the nightly [build](https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/nightly/cu100/libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-latest.zip), that ships `pytorch` with all the needed `cuda` dlls.
It looks like the conda installer for [Windows](http://conda%20install%20pytorch%20torchvision%20cudatoolkit=10.0%20-c%20pytorch) does not install the latest `pytorch stable 1.2` but an older `1.0.1`. Nightly build for Windows conda python 3.7 installs a newer `1.3`.